# How to use time command on nested command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, time

I need to use the GNU `time` command to measure a program I've written, so I
tried

```sh
/usr/bin/time -v cat test/testin | ./db retrieve >> test/result
```

But the first line in the output showed

```
Command being timed: "cat test/testin"
```

and the user time and system time were

```
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.02
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 2:02.73
```

which showed it didn't count the time used by my program since this program
should've run 2 minutes or longer with considerable CPU usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
/usr/bin/time -v ./db retrieve < test/testin >> test/result
```

[Useless use of cat](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: This also get rid of the unecessary measurement of the cost used by pipeline and redirection, thanks!

Comment: Note that `time` writes its statistics to stderr, so the redirection will not capture the timing information.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can simply omit the UUOC. In the general case, you can do

```
time sh -c "cmd | cmd"
```